# How to force Godot to recalculate control nodes size/position?

Tags: godot

Building UI in Godot 3.2.1. Of course I use anchors so UI elements are arranged within the screen automatically according to specified layout. I have UI scale system - nothing fancy - simply change font size (`DynamicFont.size`). If font size is large enough then some UI nodes may be pushed out of the screen. However, nodes don't return to normal sizes/positions with font size decreasing. The way to fix a mess is to resize game window which is not always an option and doesn't seem like a correct way to handle the issue. So how can I force Godot to recalculate control nodes size/position?

[image]

Comment: As for UI scaling, consider using the `2d` stretch mode and `expand` stretch aspect to let Godot take care of this automatically. See [Multiple resolutions](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/viewports/multiple_resolutions.html) in the documentation for more information.

Comment: @Calinou That's my case actually. I use 2D + expand. The purpose of the mentioned additional scaling is to scale UI relative to other parts (icons, images, sprites). Because text may become too large or too small depending on the screen size/resoution, distance to the screen, etc. So it's just another level of tuning for convinience. Unfortunately, Godot documentation explains only the simplest stuff.

Comment: This pull request should address this need once it's merged: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/21446
Unfortunately, it's too late to merge it into 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the parent control's minimum size to `Vector2(0, 0)` after changing the font size might do the trick:

```
$Control.rect_min_size = Vector2(0, 0)
```

If it's already set to `Vector2(0, 0)`, you may have to change it twice using `call_deferred()` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Made some progress with this technique. However, I have pretty complicated UI spread across many scenes. So I ended up looping over ALL the control nodes of ALL the scenes. For every node I do `rect_min_size = Vector2(10000, 10000)` then `rect_min_size = Vector2(0, 0)`. Don't know what `call_deferred` is. Kinda works. BUT! It's ridiculous. And a little bit laggy. Also I must move from tail to head (root).

Comment: Maybe there is a chance to somehow emit signal about window resizing so Godot can do it automatically according to the containers layout?

Comment: That can be done by connecting the root Viewport's `size_changed` signal like this: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/blob/5363f8a75a31168c3bc3ac717d8d0c26f86c82d5/viewport/3d_in_2d/3d_in_2d.gd#L18
(It'll only work when using the `disabled` or `2d` stretch modes.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe I don't get it. I don't want to handle the signal. I want to emit the signal so Godot could handle it. I see it as a virtual window resizing - Godot has the code to update containers size/position so I want to execute the code. Sounds simple. Impossible in practice.

Comment: Every Control-based node has `resized` and `minimum_size_changed` signals for that.

Comment: No luck. Control nodes' signals do nothing. You can handle them but emitting is useless. I guess Godot has another set of special/hidden/not_documented signals or bugs in emitting/handling mechanism. If I resize window manually or via script containers are updated. If I resize containers' content then containers can only become bigger and can't become smaller. Some essential signal simply not emitted. Or not handled? Bugs that will never be fixed I believe. Because devs already developing Godot 4 according to the news. Version number first. Anyway thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In your scene tree, find the top level container that contains all of the elements that you want to recalculate. This would be the lowest common ancestor in the scene tree, in computer science terminology. Now, hide the container, by setting it's 'visible' property to false. Then, add a deferred call to change it's 'visible' property back to true.

```
var your_container = $".".find_node("your-container")
your_container.visible = false
your_container.call_deferred("set_visible", true)
```

This seems to cause Godot to recalculate the layout of 'your_container'.

It looks like only CanvasItem derived classes have a 'visible' property, so you would not be able to simply set the 'visible' property on a CanvasLayer, for example.

Fortunately, Containers and Controls both derive from CannvasItem, so this methodology should work fine if your lowest common ancestor node is either a Container or a Control or other CanvasItem derived class instance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by emitting a signal from a parent element, which appears to force a refresh:

```
canvas_item.emit_signal("item_rect_changed")
```

The problem child got refreshed, and unlike the visibility method, focus was retained.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Godot 3.5.1-stable.